# Python-how to merge and not update two dictionaries with strings as keys and values as list of strings?

Tags: python, dictionary, merge, concatenation

Given two dictionaries:

```
d1={'cardinal':['VA','OH'], 'meadowlark':['OR']}
d2={'meadowlark':['WY'], 'cardinal':['VA', 'IL'], 'oriole':['MD']}
```

How do you merge them into a new dictionary **without** updating the original dictionaries **and**  concatenate duplicates like so:

```
new_dict={'cardinal':['VA','OH','VA','IL'],'meadowlark':['OR', 'WY'], 'oriole':['MD']}
```

My code doesn't concatenate correctly but here it is:

```
def merge(d1,d2):
    import collections
    a=collections.Counter(d1)
    b=collections.Counter(d2)
    return a+b
```

I'm stuck on how to concatenate the items.

Comment: yes but I can't overwrite either and I need to keep the duplicates

Comment: what happen to `IL` in d2?

Comment: I typed wrong. I just edited to the correct version.

Comment: BTW, if you don't want repeated items in your values you could use sets as the values instead of lists, so in `new_dict` the value associated with `'cardinal'` would be `{'VA', 'OH', 'IL'}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deep-copy one of the dicts, extend the values with the elements of the values from the other dict as needed.

```
>>> from copy import deepcopy
>>> d1={'cardinal':['VA','OH'], 'meadowlark':['OR']}
>>> d2={'meadowlark':['WY'], 'cardinal':['VA', 'IL'], 'oriole':['MD']}
>>> 
>>> d = deepcopy(d1)
>>> for key, lst in d2.items():
...     d.setdefault(key, []).extend(lst)
... 
>>> d
{'meadowlark': ['OR', 'WY'], 'oriole': ['MD'], 'cardinal': ['VA', 'OH', 'VA', 'IL']}
>>> d1
{'meadowlark': ['OR'], 'cardinal': ['VA', 'OH']}
>>> d2
{'meadowlark': ['WY'], 'oriole': ['MD'], 'cardinal': ['VA', 'IL']}
```

Comment: perfect timing haha

Answer (score 4):

You can create the accumulated-value dict using a *dictionary comprehension*:

```
def merge(d1, d2):
    return {k: d1.get(k, []) + d2.get(k, []) for k in d1.viewkeys()|d2.viewkeys()}

print(merge(d1, d2))
# {'meadowlark': ['OR', 'WY'], 'cardinal': ['VA', 'OH', 'VA', 'IL'], 'oriole': ['MD']}
```

Replace `.viewkeys` with `.keys` in Python 3.

---

Timings:

```
In [11]: %%timeit
    ...: merge2(d1, d2) # deepcopy-extend, timing for import excluded
    ...: 
    ...: 
100000 loops, best of 3: 11.1 µs per loop

In [13]: %%timeit
    ...: merge(d1, d2) # dict. comp.
    ...: 
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.32 µs per loop
```

Comment: Nice. It'd be interesting to compare the efficiency of the different approaches. I'm pretty sure that `.extend` is more efficient than concatenating lists with `+`; OTOH, iterating over the union of the key views is probably more efficient than looping over each dict separately.

Comment: @PM2Ring You're right, but there's a `deepcopy` before `extend`, and that will take a hit on performance. The vectorized `for` and zero assignments is another plus for the comprehension.

Comment: That's a bigger difference than I was expecting! But i guess `deepcopy` isn't cheap because it has to handle arbitrarily nested structures containing arbitrary objects, so it has to examine every item it copies.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "vectorized for": the `for` loop in a comprehension (or generator expression) is a standard Python `for` loop, not a fast C-style loop like Numpy can use when processing arrays of native machine datatypes. A list comp is faster than the equivalent traditional `for` loop and `.append` code because it uses a fast LIST_APPEND bytecode rather than calling the `.append` method, so you get the advantage of using an operator over a function call; I'm not sure what happens in dict comps...

Comment: @PM2Ring Vectorized is probably not the right word, but the for loop is not entirely the same https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ba85d69a3e3610bdd05f0dd372cf4ebca178c7fb/Python/compile.c#L3707

Comment: Ah, ok. It's more efficient than a plain `for` loop because: "This code *knows* that the loop cannot contain break, continue, or return, so it cheats and skips the SETUP_LOOP/POP_BLOCK steps used in normal loops."

Answer (score 1):

You can go do it simple, step by step:

```
 d1={'cardinal':['VA','OH'], 'meadowlark':['OR']}

d2={'meadowlark':['WY'], 'cardinal':['VA', 'IL'], 'oriole':['MD']}

new_d = d1.copy()

for k, v in d2.items():
    if k not in new_d:
        new_d[k] = v
    else:
        new_d[k] = new_d[k] + v
```

It doesn't look cool but it works :)

Comment: Please explain :)

Comment: Oops, I had missed the copy part, but then you'll need to `deepcopy` to create new lists for the new dict.

Comment: As I said in my answer, merely doing `d1.copy()` will re-use the lists of `d1` in `new_d`, so when you do `new_d[k] += v` that will modify `d1`. You _could_ use `deepcopy`, or simply do `new_d[k] = new_d[k] + v` which will assign a new list to `new_d[k]`

Comment: That is one nice explanation, I edited my answer based on you comment.

Answer (score 1):

This code is similar to timgeb's except we do the deep copying manually. The deep copy is necessary to prevent mutating the original lists. A shallow copy of a dict (eg, using the `dict.copy` method) makes a new dict object, but it re-uses the original dict keys and values. And as you've noticed, that can cause problems when the values are mutable (dict keys shouldn't be mutable).

```
def append_dict(new_dict, old_dict):
    for k, v in old_dict.items():
        new_dict.setdefault(k, []).extend(v)

d1 = {'cardinal':['VA','OH'], 'meadowlark':['OR']}
d2 = {'meadowlark':['WY'], 'cardinal':['VA', 'IL'], 'oriole':['MD']}

new_dict = {}
append_dict(new_dict, d1)
append_dict(new_dict, d2)

print('new', new_dict)
print('d1', d1)
print('d2', d2)
```

**output**

```
new {'cardinal': ['VA', 'OH', 'VA', 'IL'], 'meadowlark': ['OR', 'WY'], 'oriole': ['MD']}
d1 {'cardinal': ['VA', 'OH'], 'meadowlark': ['OR']}
d2 {'meadowlark': ['WY'], 'cardinal': ['VA', 'IL'], 'oriole': ['MD']}
```